# How do I transfer my battlefield 4 data to my ps4

Tags: battlefield-4, ps4

I have Battlefield 4 (BF4) for my ps3 and my ps4 and when I started bf4 up on my ps4 it asked if I wanted to transfer my ps3 bf4 data to my ps4 and I accidentally pressed NO and I wanted to press yes is there any way I can get that to pop back up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to contact DICE support directly and see if they can help you out.

That dialog is a one-time only deal.